# calculate date(formula field) based on two fields

Tags: formula, formula-field

Start and End Dates need to be calculated date fields (formula) based on the Fiscal_Year_Start_Date__c field on the Account and the Fiscal_Year__c.
Example: If Fiscal_Year__c = 2013 and Account.Fiscal_Year_Start_Date__c = 7/1/1990, Start Date = 7/1/2013 and End Date = 6/30/2014

Fiscal_Year__c is of type Picklist
Fiscal_Year_Start_Date__c is Formula field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about as a start.

startDate:

```
DATE(VALUE(TEXT(Fiscal_Year__c)),MONTH(Fiscal_Year_Start_Date__c),DAY(Fiscal_Year_Start_Date__c))
```

endDate is a bit more problematic in a formula field. In Apex you could just do a `addDays(-1)` to get the EndDate and cleanly roll around months and years. In a formula field you are probably going to need a combination of CASE, IF and MOD statements.

You might be able to do some arithmetic based on 1440 being the number of hours is a day, but I haven't tried it yet.

See [Adding Days, Months, and Years to a Date](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&language=en_US#adding-dmy-to-date)

I haven't tried it, but maybe the following will work.

```
DATE(VALUE(TEXT(Fiscal_Year__c)),MONTH(Fiscal_Year_Start_Date__c),DAY(Fiscal_Year_Start_Date__c)) - 1
```

Comment: Fiscal_Year__c is a field type of picklist

Comment: @sf.dev I've added `VALUE()` to the formula to convert the picklist value to a number.

Comment: I am getting an error .Error: Field Fiscal_Year__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Comment: @sf.dev might need to convert it to text first. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Great Work, Can you help me to resolve my question 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237892/create-formula-field-based-on-report-created-date